# How to fix error in gam() in mgcv 'Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid model formula in ExtractVars'

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I cannot solve this seemingly simple error message when fitting gam() in mgcv package. Any help greatly appreciated.

'Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid model formula in ExtractVars'

I have read all similar posts that can be found on stackoverflow, but still have not be able to solve this issue. Some other posts seem to suggest that this can occur if variable names include spaces, but this is not the case for my error.

## load package

```
library(mgcv)
```

## read in data

```
join <- read.csv("join.csv", header = TRUE)
```

## define factors

```
join$site <- factor(join$site)
join$season <- factor(join$season)
join$RHDV_transmis_cat <- factor(join$RHDV_transmis_cat)
join$RHDV2_arrive_cat <- factor(join$RHDV2_arrive_cat)
```

## run model

```
gam_1 <- gam(RHDV_transmis_cat ~  s(age) + s(weight) + s(site) + s(RCV) + s(season, bs = "cc") + s(preceeding_mth_temp) + s(preceeding_mth_rain) + s(RHDV2_arrive_cat) + s(abun_adjust_dist) + te(abun_adjust_dist, RHDV2_arrive_cat, by ="fs") + s(RHDV2_arrive_cat, season, bs = "re"), data = join, family = binomial, method = "REML", select = TRUE)
```

[Data available at here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oLdT1GkgBdNwW-Bsi195DwTRMH2Qo84S)

Comment: Did you also receive errors due to the using factor variables in the smooth function (and not as a random effect)

Comment: No I have not received errors for using factors in smooth functions, but am new to using GAMs so would be keen to hear if this is not generally advisable/possible?

Comment: No I dont think its sensible to use factors in the smooth (unless they are used as random effects). For example, say in an ordinary linear regression where you add a x^2 term on a continuous variable you wouldn't try to do this sort of transformation on a categorical ... same applies to splines.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding and a typo. Note in the `te()` smooth that you have `by = "fs"` where I think you meant to use `bs = "fs"`.

Secondly, if you want an `”fs”` smooth, you don’t use `te()`, you use `s()` to set it up. Where you have

```
te(abun_adjust_dist, RHDV2_arrive_cat, by = "fs")
```

You want

```
s(abun_adjust_dist, RHDV2_arrive_cat, bs = "fs")
```

Assuming you want a random smooth of `abun_adjust_dist` for the levels of `RHDV2_arrive_cat`.